# Pass Jquery variable to PHP variable in same page

Tags: php, jquery

I'm trying to pass a Jquery variable (items) to a php variable $itemdestination on the same page, when pushing the button     .bid, which is a submit button:

```
<script>
    $(".bid").click(function () {
        var items = $(this).closest("tr")   // Finds the closest row <tr> 
            .find(".nr")     // Gets a descendent with class="nr"
            .text();         // Retrieves the text within <td>
        var itemdestination = $(this).closest("tr")   // Finds the closest row <tr> 
            .find(".no")     // Gets a descendent with class="nr"
            .text();

        $("#prøve").append(items, itemdestination);       // Outputs the answer

        $.ajax({
            url: 'Jobs.php',
            type: 'POST',
            data: {items: items}
        });
    });
</script>

<?php

if (isset($_POST['button_pressed'])) {

    $itemdestination = $_POST['items'];

    //Email information
    $admin_email = "admin@speditionhub.com";
    $email = $userName;
    $subject = "Bid registered on your cargo";
    $comment = $itemdestination;

    echo $admin_email;
    echo $comment;

  //send email
  mail($email, "$subject", $comment, "From:" . $admin_email);

  }
?>
 <script>
alert("Your bid is registered");
</script>
<?php

}
?>
```

But nothing is passed with the method i'm using. What am I doing wrong??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Isn't this:

```
if(isset($_POST['button_pressed']))
```

should be:

```
if(isset($_POST['items']))
```

---

Seems that you are checking for wrong posted variable.

Comment: It does work according to passing the variable. But then the alert is never coming, when the button is pushed?

Comment: @NicolajNyegaard i don't see any alert(). in your code.

Comment: sorry, that's because I forgot the rest of the code. It is edited in the original post know.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the following if statement and try:

```
if(isset($_POST['button_pressed']))
```

Comment: But $_POST['items']; is still PHP variable ,please read OP's Question.

Comment: $_POST['items'] is not mentioned in the question.  The word "with" suggests the problem is with the caller - the AJAX request.  Perhaps you can clarify (edit) the question? Or provide an interpretation?

Answer (score 1):

You need to set a post field for button_pressed in you js (in order for your php to run), then actually do something with the returned data:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'Jobs.php',
    type: 'POST',
    data: {items: items, button_pressed: true},
    success: function(data){
        console.log(data);//do something with the data returned
    }
});
```

EDIT if this bound to the click event on a submit button, you must stop the form submitting normally with event.preventDefault :

```
$(".bid").click(function (ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
    //the rest of your code here
```

Comment: This does work, but then the e-mail is sent out twice. The first with the passed varaible, and the second mail is just blank?

Comment: @NicolajNyegaard then the script is being called twice, once from ajax, one from somewhere else. is `.bid` a submit button by any chance? I will edit with a solution if so

Comment: yes .bid is a submit button whit the bid as the id.